# Kernel module makefile - How to make a static library from objects and then link with another object to make the final module

Tags: static, makefile, kernel

I have the following Makefile for a kernel module:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS+=-DLINUX_DRIVER -mhard-float

obj-m += main.o
other-objs := Obj.o Obj1.o Obj2.o Obj2.o ...
```

Question:

How can I first make a static lib from all the objects and only then link with the main object with the created static lib?

I know how to make this process manually in two steps. First I call the version above. then I call:

```
ar rcs libother.a Obj.o Obj1.o ...
```

And then I change the makefile to:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS+=-DLINUX_DRIVER -mhard-float

obj-m += main.o libother.a
```

Since I don't master Makefiles I wonder if anyone knows a quick and clean solution for this.

Thanks,

Nuno

Answer (score 2):

I will answer to my own question. I found in [Kernel Makefile documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/makefiles.html#library-file-goals-lib-y) the following:

> **3.5 Library file goals - lib-y**
> Objects listed with obj-* are used for modules, or
> combined in a built-in.o for that specific directory.
> There is also the possibility to list objects that will
> be included in a library, lib.a.
> All objects listed with lib-y are combined in a single
> library for that directory.

So, what I did was to change the make file to look like this:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS+=-DLINUX_DRIVER -mhard-float

obj-m += main.o lib.a
lib-y := Obj.o Obj1.o Obj2.o Obj2.o ...
```

I don't knwo why, but the suggested answers were making the makefile "forget" it was a kernel makefile and all the kernel includes and addition defines in the extra flags were being ignored.

Hope it helps someone in the future,

With my best regards,

Nuno Santos

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to your `Makefile`:

```
libother.a: $(other-objs)
    ar cr $@ $<
```

Comment: When doing this way it seems that the Makefile forgot all about the context it was working on, no kernel includes and the EXTRA_FLAGS is not taken into account. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
#your variable definitions here

all: your_module_name

your_module_name: main.o libother.a
    gcc $(YOUR_OPTIONS_HERE) -o your_module_name main.o -L. -lother

libother.a: $(other-objs)
    ar rcs $@ $^

main.o: main.c 

#your .o file dependencies here, if needed

.PHONY: all
```

This way your module will depend on both main.o and libother.a, while libother.a will be remade whenever any of other-objs is changed

Note that the library is linked via `-lother` option (as it is usually done with libraries). You will also need to specify that the current directory should be included in library search path with `-L.`